# How to stack tables on top of each other in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

I have written the following code in LaTeX for three tables. But it all are distorted over the page. I want them to be centered on the page and stacked on above each other. Any solutions to this?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \begin{document}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
    \centering
    \emph{\textbf{mstatus}} & \textbf{Marital Status}   \\\midrule
    & \emph{Value}    & \emph{Label} \\ 
    & 1 & Single\\ 
    & 2 & Married\\ 
    & 3 & Common-law marriage\\ 
    & 4 & Divorced\\ 
    & 5 & Seperated\\ 
    & 6 & Widowed\\\bottomrule
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
    \emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Education Level}   \\\midrule
    & \emph{Value}    & \emph{Label} \\ 
    & 1 & None/school\\ 
    & 2 & Middle school/high school\\ 
    & 3 & University/post-secondary\\\bottomrule
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
    \emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Urban/Rural Cluster }   \\\midrule
    & \emph{Value}    & \emph{Label} \\ 
    & 0 & Urban\\ 
    & 1 & Rurall\\ \bottomrule
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \vspace{\baselineskip}
    \end{document}
```

Edit:
I have tried the second solution, which gives me an error.

```
    \begin{table}[p]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}    
    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{mstatus}} & \textbf{Marital Status}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & Single                    \\
    2                   & Married                   \\
    3                   & Common-law marriage       \\
    4                   & Divorced                  \\
    5                   & Separated                 \\
    6                   & Widowed                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Education Level}  \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & None/school               \\
    2                   & Middle school/high school \\
    3                   & University/post-secondary \\
    \bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\textbf{\emph{ur}} & \textbf{Urban/Rural Cluster}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    0                   & Urban                     \\
    1                   & Rurall                    \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1 & 15---29\\ 
    2 & 30---44\\ 
    3 & 45---59\\ 
    4 & 60+\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
1 & Amerindian\\ 
2 & Afro-Surinamese\\ 
3 & Mixed\\ 
4 & Hindustani ("East Indians”)\\ 
5 & Javanese\\ 
6 & Maroons\\
7 & Other\\\bottomrule
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
1 & A salaried employee of the government\\
&  or an independent state-owned enterprise\\ 
2 & A salaried employee in the private sector\\ 
3 & Owner or partner in a business/Self-employed\\ 
4 & Unpaid worker
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
0 & 0\\ 
1 & SRD 0 – SRD 200\\ 
2 & SRD 200 – SRD 300\\ 
3 & SRD 301 – SRD 400\\ 
4 & SRD 401 – SRD 600\\ 
5 & SRD 601 – SRD 800\\
6 & SRD 801 – SRD 900\\ 
7 & SRD 901 – SRD 1000\\ 
8 & SRD 1001 – SRD 1200\\ 
9 & SRD 1201 – SRD 1500\\ 
10 & SRD 1501 – SRD 1800\\ 
11 & SRD 1801 – SRD 2400\\
12 & SRD 2401 – SRD 3000\\ 
13 & SRD 3001 – SRD 3600\\ 
14 & SRD SRD 3601 – SRD 4800\\ 
15 &SRD 4801 – SRD 6000\\
16 &SRD 6000+
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Regarding your recent edit: There is a `\\ ` missing before the `\bottomrule` in the last two tables. Apart from that, your tables do not fit onto a single page. Do you want a page break just between the tables or would a pagebreak within a table also be fine?

Comment: If you replace `\begin{table}` with `{`, `\end{table}` with `}`, `\vspace{\baselineskip}` with the slightly smaller `\medskip` and all occurences of `\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}` with `\begin{tabularx}{0.8\linewidth}`, you should get an output such as: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cTvG.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `tabularx` package and prescribe equal column width in each table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}

%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[p]
    \centering
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}    
    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{mstatus}} & \textbf{Marital Status}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & Single                    \\
    2                   & Married                   \\
    3                   & Common-law marriage       \\
    4                   & Divorced                  \\
    5                   & Separated                 \\
    6                   & Widowed                   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Education Level}  \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & None/school               \\
    2                   & Middle school/high school \\
    3                   & University/post-secondary \\
    \bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabularx}

\vspace{\baselineskip}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\textbf{\emph{edlevel}} & \textbf{Urban/Rural Cluster}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    0                   & Urban                     \\
    1                   & Rurall                    \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Errors which you done with adding new tables in my proposed solution are noted in @leandriis comment below you question. Reusing it:

- you need to be precise at tables writing, before each horizontal tule in table body had to table row termination (`\\` or `\tabularnewline`)
- since tables can occupy more than one page, it had not be put in `table` float anymore. Instead it, you can use `begin{center} ...` \end{center}`:

```
...
\begin{center}
<your tables>
\end{center}
```

Considering new aspect of your problem, you may consider to use `xltabular` table environment, defined in the package of the same name  instead of `tabularx`. This package combine `longtable` and `tabularx` features. Using them and extended tale's width to text width, you can write the following solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, xltabular}

%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{>{\centering}p{4em}  X}
    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{mstatus}} & \textbf{Marital Status}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & Single                    \\
    2                   & Married                   \\
    3                   & Common-law marriage       \\
    4                   & Divorced                  \\
    5                   & Separated                 \\
    6                   & Widowed                   \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
\emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Education Level}  \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & None/school               \\
    2                   & Middle school/high school \\
    3                   & University/post-secondary \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
\textbf{\emph{edlevel}} & \textbf{Urban/Rural Cluster}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    0                   & Urban                     \\
    1                   & Rurall                    \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & 15---29\\
    2                   & 30---44\\
    3                   & 45---59\\
    4                   & 60+\\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}              \\
    \addlinespace
    1                   & Amerindian                \\
    2                   & Afro-Surinamese           \\
    3                   & Mixed                     \\
    4                   & Hindustani ("East Indians”)\\
    5                   & Javanese                  \\
    6                   & Maroons                   \\
    7                   & Other                     \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}   \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}      \\
    \addlinespace
    1   & A salaried employee of the 
          government or an independent 
          state-owned enterprise            \\
    2   & A salaried employee in the 
          private sector                    \\
    3   & Owner or partner in a 
          business/Self-employed            \\
    4   & Unpaid worker                     \\
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
\textbf{\emph{age}} & \textbf{Age Group}    \\
    \midrule
\emph{Value}            & \emph{Label}      \\
    \addlinespace
    0   & 0                                 \\
    1   & SRD 0 – SRD 200                   \\
    2   & SRD 200 – SRD 300                 \\
    3   & SRD 301 – SRD 400                 \\
    4   & SRD 401 – SRD 600                 \\
    5   & SRD 601 – SRD 800                 \\
    6   & SRD 801 – SRD 900                 \\
    7   & SRD 901 – SRD 1000                \\
    8   & SRD 1001 – SRD 1200               \\
    9   & SRD 1201 – SRD 1500               \\
    10  & SRD 1501 – SRD 1800               \\
    11  & SRD 1801 – SRD 2400               \\
    12  & SRD 2401 – SRD 3000               \\
    13  & SRD 3001 – SRD 3600               \\
    14  & SRD SRD 3601 – SRD 4800           \\
    15  & SRD 4801 – SRD 6000               \\
    16  & SRD 6000+                         \\                         
    \bottomrule
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

Above MWE generate two page long table:

[image]

If you like to add even more tables, insert their table body before `\bottomrule` and separate from ˙existing one by

```
    \midrule
    \addlinespace
    \midrule
```

Comment: I have tried to add more tables but then I get an error.

Comment: @vahis100, which error? How you add additional tables? Please, clarify!

Comment: Check the edited codes in my question.

Comment: @vahis100, errors which you make at adding new table to my solution are described in *leandriis* comments below your question. See edited answer with new proposition, how can you write your tables as one, long table.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

Pull that `\centering` out of the tabular and add two `\vfill`s plus two `\vspace*{\baselineskip}`s between tabulars. There are other solutions, but this seems the easy route.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % <-- just to show margins, remove in real document
\begin{document}
\topskip0pt
\centering
~\vfill

\begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{mstatus}} & \textbf{Marital Status}   \\\midrule
& \emph{Value}    & \emph{Label} \\ 
& 1 & Single\\ 
& 2 & Married\\ 
& 3 & Common-law marriage\\ 
& 4 & Divorced\\ 
& 5 & Seperated\\ 
& 6 & Widowed\\\bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Education Level}   \\\midrule
& \emph{Value}    & \emph{Label} \\ 
& 1 & None/school\\ 
& 2 & Middle school/high school\\ 
& 3 & University/post-secondary\\\bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\vspace*{\baselineskip}

\begin{tabular}{@{} *5l @{}}    \toprule
\emph{\textbf{edlevel}} & \textbf{Urban/Rural Cluster }   \\\midrule
& \emph{Value}    & \emph{Label} \\ 
& 0 & Urban\\ 
& 1 & Rurall\\ \bottomrule
 \hline
\end{tabular}

\vfill~

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried to add more tables, but then I get an error. Please see my edit.